# The command ".\Scripts\activate" is not working

Tags: python

I am trying to set up the virtual environment but when I type the command ".\Scripts\activate", I get an error message "You must 'source' this script"

Comment: Hello! Have you tried `.\Scripts\activate.bat`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `source ./Scripts/activate` to activate virtualenv